# Python + operator used with list type

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Let's say my list a is [1,2,3] which points to address 53367992

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> id(a)
53367992
```

Now, when I add [9] to this list, I understand the change of address, now l points to 53368552

```
>>> a = a + [9]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 9]
>>> id(a)
53368552
```

In this below case, I do not understand why a is pointing to same address even after adding [4] to a

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> id(a)
53361720
>>> a += [9]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 9]
>>> id(a)
53361720
```

Could you guys please explain me what is the difference between a = a +[9] 
and a += [9] (how come this acts as appending) operation in list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a list is mutable. methods like `.append()` (or `+=` / `__iadd__` for that matter) change the list itself (in-place) and do not create a new instance.

`+` (`__add__`) on the other hand will return a fresh instance.

Comment: thank you for the answer @hiro, didn't know += statement is different from + statement